Is there a way to use R 4.4.1 in GCP Vertex AI Workbench Instances?
Is there a way to use R 4.4.1 in GCP Vertex AI Workbench Instances? Currently, only user-managed notebooks have access to R 4.4, not even 4.4.1. And it will be deprecated in January 2025.
I've tried installing R via terminal in a Vertex Instance but it doesnt show up as a usable kernel for my ipynb notebooks that contain R code.

So far I've gotten R to run by specifying gcr.io/deeplearning-platform-release/r-cpu.4-4:latest as my custom container, but it is still not 4.4.1.
